# Getting Carousel 3D Spinner item image from selector

Tags: android, 3d, spinner, selector

I downloaded sample android carousel demo source code in below link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

I am working on a 3D carousel spinner for Android but I want to make icons changed when the item is selected or focused.I tried selector xml for drawable but it doesnt work. So do you have any idea how can i use selector on 3D carousel spinner?